# Removing first elements of tuples in a list

Tags: python

I have a list of tuples as follows:

```
values = [('1', 'hi', 'you'), ('2',' bye', 'bye')]
```

However, the first element of each tuple is not needed. The desired output is:

```
[('hi', 'you'), (' bye', 'bye')]
```

I've done enough research to know I can't manipulate tuples but I can't seem to find an answer on how to successfully remove the first element of each tuple in the list.

Comment: An another approach  **a_list = map(lambda x: tuple(x[1:]), reader)**

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Firstly tuple is immutable.

Secondly try this approach using a list comprehension:

```
a_list = [el[1:] for el in values]
```

Check [**`slice notation`**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/explain-pythons-slice-notation).

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following list comprehension if tuples are not required:

```
a_list = [a_tuple[1:] for a_tuple in values]
print(a_list)
```

This would print the following:

```
[('hi', 'you'), (' bye', 'bye')]
```